# SQL Selecting the latest and removing the duplicates

Tags: sql

Hello I have a query here:

```
SELECT Erp.QuoteDtl.Company
 ,Erp.OrderHed.ShipToNum
 ,Erp.OrderHed.PONum
 ,Erp.OrderDtl.PartNum
 ,Erp.OrderHed.OrderNum
 ,Erp.OrderHed.OrderDate
 ,Erp.QuoteDtl.QuoteNum
 ,Erp.QuoteHed.DateQuoted
 ,Erp.QuoteHed.ExpirationDate
 ,Erp.Customer.CustID
FROM Erp.OrderHed
INNER JOIN Erp.Customer ON Erp.OrderHed.Company = Erp.Customer.Company
 AND Erp.OrderHed.CustNum = Erp.Customer.CustNum
INNER JOIN Erp.OrderDtl ON Erp.OrderHed.Company = Erp.OrderDtl.Company
 AND Erp.OrderHed.OrderNum = Erp.OrderDtl.OrderNum
 AND Erp.OrderHed.CustNum = Erp.OrderDtl.CustNum
INNER JOIN Erp.QuoteDtl ON Erp.OrderHed.Company = Erp.QuoteDtl.Company
 AND Erp.OrderDtl.PartNum = Erp.QuoteDtl.PartNum
INNER JOIN Erp.QuoteHed ON Erp.OrderHed.Company = Erp.QuoteHed.Company
INNER JOIN Erp.Part ON Erp.OrderHed.Company = Erp.Part.Company
 AND Erp.OrderDtl.PartNum = Erp.Part.PartNum
WHERE (Erp.OrderHed.OrderDate >= '6/15/2021')
 AND (Erp.QuoteHed.DateQuoted <= '2021-06-15')
 AND (Erp.QuoteHed.ExpirationDate >= '2021-06-15')
 AND (Erp.QuoteDtl.Company = N'CYT')
GROUP BY OrderDtl.PartNum
 ,Erp.QuoteDtl.Company
 ,Erp.OrderHed.ShipToNum
 ,Erp.OrderHed.PONum
 ,Erp.OrderDtl.PartNum
 ,Erp.OrderHed.OrderNum
 ,Erp.OrderHed.OrderDate
 ,Erp.QuoteDtl.QuoteNum
 ,Erp.QuoteHed.DateQuoted
 ,Erp.QuoteHed.ExpirationDate
 ,Erp.Customer.CustID
ORDER BY QuoteNum
```

Still currently trying to build it, this is the results I get

[image]

So my goal is to select only 1 `PartNum` for the latest `DateQuoted`

So in this case it will only show 1 row for `PartNum`

Desired Results Would be

```
CYT | NKP | 188719 | 26251-RJ2-0000 | 207504 | 11373 | 2021-06-01
CYT | BAC | 188719 | 18130-TLA-0000 | 207509 | 12250 | 2021-06-01
```

then a new part under that one with same concept.

Answer (score 0):

To get single row for each cust_id and part part numbers you can use row_number() ranking window function as below:

```
  WITH CTE AS
    (
      SELECT Erp.QuoteDtl.Company, Erp.OrderHed.ShipToNum, Erp.OrderHed.PONum, Erp.OrderDtl.PartNum, Erp.OrderHed.OrderNum, Erp.OrderHed.OrderDate, Erp.QuoteDtl.QuoteNum, Erp.QuoteHed.DateQuoted, Erp.QuoteHed.ExpirationDate,
                             Erp.Customer.CustID,ROW_NUMBER()OVER(PARTITION BY Erp.Customer.CustID, Erp.OrderDtl.PartNum ORDER BY DateQuoted desc )RNK
      FROM            Erp.OrderHed INNER JOIN
                             Erp.Customer ON Erp.OrderHed.Company = Erp.Customer.Company AND Erp.OrderHed.CustNum = Erp.Customer.CustNum INNER JOIN
                             Erp.OrderDtl ON Erp.OrderHed.Company = Erp.OrderDtl.Company AND Erp.OrderHed.OrderNum = Erp.OrderDtl.OrderNum AND Erp.OrderHed.CustNum = Erp.OrderDtl.CustNum INNER JOIN
                             Erp.QuoteDtl ON Erp.OrderHed.Company = Erp.QuoteDtl.Company AND Erp.OrderDtl.PartNum = Erp.QuoteDtl.PartNum INNER JOIN
                             Erp.QuoteHed ON Erp.OrderHed.Company = Erp.QuoteHed.Company INNER JOIN
                             Erp.Part ON Erp.OrderHed.Company = Erp.Part.Company AND Erp.OrderDtl.PartNum = Erp.Part.PartNum
      WHERE        (Erp.OrderHed.OrderDate >= '6/15/2021') AND (Erp.QuoteHed.DateQuoted <= '2021-06-15') AND (Erp.QuoteHed.ExpirationDate >= '2021-06-15') AND (Erp.QuoteDtl.Company = N'CYT')
      Group by OrderDtl.PartNum, Erp.QuoteDtl.Company, Erp.OrderHed.ShipToNum, Erp.OrderHed.PONum, Erp.OrderDtl.PartNum, Erp.OrderHed.OrderNum, Erp.OrderHed.OrderDate, Erp.QuoteDtl.QuoteNum, Erp.QuoteHed.DateQuoted, Erp.QuoteHed.ExpirationDate, Erp.Customer.CustID 
    )
    SELECT Erp.QuoteDtl.Company, Erp.OrderHed.ShipToNum, Erp.OrderHed.PONum, Erp.OrderDtl.PartNum, Erp.OrderHed.OrderNum, Erp.OrderHed.OrderDate, Erp.QuoteDtl.QuoteNum, Erp.QuoteHed.DateQuoted, Erp.QuoteHed.ExpirationDate, Erp.Customer.CustID
    FROM CTE
    WHERE RNK=1
```

If you are using sql server then you can use `top 1` `order by DateQuoted desc`

```
SELECT TOP 1 Erp.QuoteDtl.Company
 ,Erp.OrderHed.ShipToNum
 ,Erp.OrderHed.PONum
 ,Erp.OrderDtl.PartNum
 ,Erp.OrderHed.OrderNum
 ,Erp.OrderHed.OrderDate
 ,Erp.QuoteDtl.QuoteNum
 ,Erp.QuoteHed.DateQuoted
 ,Erp.QuoteHed.ExpirationDate
 ,Erp.Customer.CustID
FROM Erp.OrderHed
INNER JOIN Erp.Customer ON Erp.OrderHed.Company = Erp.Customer.Company
 AND Erp.OrderHed.CustNum = Erp.Customer.CustNum
INNER JOIN Erp.OrderDtl ON Erp.OrderHed.Company = Erp.OrderDtl.Company
 AND Erp.OrderHed.OrderNum = Erp.OrderDtl.OrderNum
 AND Erp.OrderHed.CustNum = Erp.OrderDtl.CustNum
INNER JOIN Erp.QuoteDtl ON Erp.OrderHed.Company = Erp.QuoteDtl.Company
 AND Erp.OrderDtl.PartNum = Erp.QuoteDtl.PartNum
INNER JOIN Erp.QuoteHed ON Erp.OrderHed.Company = Erp.QuoteHed.Company
INNER JOIN Erp.Part ON Erp.OrderHed.Company = Erp.Part.Company
 AND Erp.OrderDtl.PartNum = Erp.Part.PartNum
WHERE (Erp.OrderHed.OrderDate >= '6/15/2021')
 AND (Erp.QuoteHed.DateQuoted <= '2021-06-15')
 AND (Erp.QuoteHed.ExpirationDate >= '2021-06-15')
 AND (Erp.QuoteDtl.Company = N'CYT')
GROUP BY OrderDtl.PartNum
 ,Erp.QuoteDtl.Company
 ,Erp.OrderHed.ShipToNum
 ,Erp.OrderHed.PONum
 ,Erp.OrderDtl.PartNum
 ,Erp.OrderHed.OrderNum
 ,Erp.OrderHed.OrderDate
 ,Erp.QuoteDtl.QuoteNum
 ,Erp.QuoteHed.DateQuoted
 ,Erp.QuoteHed.ExpirationDate
 ,Erp.Customer.CustID
ORDER BY DateQuoted DESC
```

If you are using MySQL then it will be

```
SELECT Erp.QuoteDtl.Company
 ,Erp.OrderHed.ShipToNum
 ,Erp.OrderHed.PONum
 ,Erp.OrderDtl.PartNum
 ,Erp.OrderHed.OrderNum
 ,Erp.OrderHed.OrderDate
 ,Erp.QuoteDtl.QuoteNum
 ,Erp.QuoteHed.DateQuoted
 ,Erp.QuoteHed.ExpirationDate
 ,Erp.Customer.CustID
FROM Erp.OrderHed
INNER JOIN Erp.Customer ON Erp.OrderHed.Company = Erp.Customer.Company
 AND Erp.OrderHed.CustNum = Erp.Customer.CustNum
INNER JOIN Erp.OrderDtl ON Erp.OrderHed.Company = Erp.OrderDtl.Company
 AND Erp.OrderHed.OrderNum = Erp.OrderDtl.OrderNum
 AND Erp.OrderHed.CustNum = Erp.OrderDtl.CustNum
INNER JOIN Erp.QuoteDtl ON Erp.OrderHed.Company = Erp.QuoteDtl.Company
 AND Erp.OrderDtl.PartNum = Erp.QuoteDtl.PartNum
INNER JOIN Erp.QuoteHed ON Erp.OrderHed.Company = Erp.QuoteHed.Company
INNER JOIN Erp.Part ON Erp.OrderHed.Company = Erp.Part.Company
 AND Erp.OrderDtl.PartNum = Erp.Part.PartNum
WHERE (Erp.OrderHed.OrderDate >= '6/15/2021')
 AND (Erp.QuoteHed.DateQuoted <= '2021-06-15')
 AND (Erp.QuoteHed.ExpirationDate >= '2021-06-15')
 AND (Erp.QuoteDtl.Company = N'CYT')
GROUP BY OrderDtl.PartNum
 ,Erp.QuoteDtl.Company
 ,Erp.OrderHed.ShipToNum
 ,Erp.OrderHed.PONum
 ,Erp.OrderDtl.PartNum
 ,Erp.OrderHed.OrderNum
 ,Erp.OrderHed.OrderDate
 ,Erp.QuoteDtl.QuoteNum
 ,Erp.QuoteHed.DateQuoted
 ,Erp.QuoteHed.ExpirationDate
 ,Erp.Customer.CustID
ORDER BY DateQuoted DESC Limit 1
```

Comment: Yes that only returns 1 row. I need it to return all of the rows for each part number, So I don't have duplicate part numbers on each `CustID` https://prnt.sc/15lvixu (Picture for reference)

Comment: @SmackYouIn2.3 got you now. I have revised my answer.

Comment: In this I cam getting `invalid column name 'RNK'

Comment: it is missing the FROM part : `SELECT Erp.QuoteDtl.Company, Erp.OrderHed.ShipToNum, Erp.OrderHed.PONum, Erp.OrderDtl.PartNum, Erp.OrderHed.OrderNum, Erp.OrderHed.OrderDate, Erp.QuoteDtl.QuoteNum, Erp.QuoteHed.DateQuoted, Erp.QuoteHed.ExpirationDate, Erp.Customer.CustID FROM CTE WHERE RNK=1`

Comment: Thanks a lot @DonKnacki. I have revised the answer.

Answer (score 0):

you could use the `max()` function on `DateQuoted`, removing it from the group by statement.

Comment: Could you demonstrate how you would do that so I can give it a try? This query was built with a query builder in report builder.

Comment: As @DonKnacki mentioned in his answer. I was just thinking, do you need the `ExpirationDate` in your result? because that field in the `group by` statement will still duplicate the results for each `PartNum` (it's always different) and the suggested solution is not enough..

Answer (score 0):

as explain by @fra: using max should work

```
SELECT Erp.QuoteDtl.Company
 ,Erp.OrderHed.ShipToNum
 ,Erp.OrderHed.PONum
 ,Erp.OrderDtl.PartNum
 ,Erp.OrderHed.OrderNum
 ,Erp.OrderHed.OrderDate
 ,Erp.QuoteDtl.QuoteNum
 ,max(Erp.QuoteHed.DateQuoted)
 ,Erp.QuoteHed.ExpirationDate
 ,Erp.Customer.CustID
FROM Erp.OrderHed
INNER JOIN Erp.Customer ON Erp.OrderHed.Company = Erp.Customer.Company
 AND Erp.OrderHed.CustNum = Erp.Customer.CustNum
INNER JOIN Erp.OrderDtl ON Erp.OrderHed.Company = Erp.OrderDtl.Company
 AND Erp.OrderHed.OrderNum = Erp.OrderDtl.OrderNum
 AND Erp.OrderHed.CustNum = Erp.OrderDtl.CustNum
INNER JOIN Erp.QuoteDtl ON Erp.OrderHed.Company = Erp.QuoteDtl.Company
 AND Erp.OrderDtl.PartNum = Erp.QuoteDtl.PartNum
INNER JOIN Erp.QuoteHed ON Erp.OrderHed.Company = Erp.QuoteHed.Company
INNER JOIN Erp.Part ON Erp.OrderHed.Company = Erp.Part.Company
 AND Erp.OrderDtl.PartNum = Erp.Part.PartNum
WHERE (Erp.OrderHed.OrderDate >= '6/15/2021')
 AND (Erp.QuoteHed.DateQuoted <= '2021-06-15')
 AND (Erp.QuoteHed.ExpirationDate >= '2021-06-15')
 AND (Erp.QuoteDtl.Company = N'CYT')
GROUP BY OrderDtl.PartNum
 ,Erp.QuoteDtl.Company
 ,Erp.OrderHed.ShipToNum
 ,Erp.OrderHed.PONum
 ,Erp.OrderDtl.PartNum
 ,Erp.OrderHed.OrderNum
 ,Erp.OrderHed.OrderDate
 ,Erp.QuoteDtl.QuoteNum
 ,Erp.QuoteHed.ExpirationDate
 ,Erp.Customer.CustID
ORDER BY QuoteNum
```

Comment: With this query I am still getting duplicates for `PartNum` I even took out `ExpirationDate` and this is the result https://prnt.sc/15m1dhx

Comment: yes because you have different PONum, what do to in such cases ?